# Invalid or missing activities in HTTP body - error as a response to

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

We are trying to connect Unity app with Chatbot using https://github.com/tompaana/bot-direct-line-for-unity. Starting a new conversation with bot is working properly, but when I try to send a message to it, instead of getting a response I end up with error attached below. Bot is working properly with web/skype, only problem we have is our unity implementation.

I wonder what we are missing in the POST in order to receive a proper response from bot.

Because Unity is somewhat missing features like Network/XHR from browsers developer toolkit, we used Fiddler to get those results:

here is POST sent to chatbot:

```js
POST https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/CRar7Qz6VaEmIeMR6UmUC/activities HTTP/1.1
Host: directline.botframework.com
User-Agent: UnityPlayer/2017.3.1f1 (UnityWebRequest/1.0, libcurl/7.51.0-DEV)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Authorization: Bearer XXX.edited_out.XXX
Content-Type: application/json
X-Unity-Version: 2017.3.1f1

76
{ "type": "message", "channelId": "directline", "from": { "id": "default-user", "name": "User" }, "text": "message text" }
0
```

here is the response:

```js
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 116
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:91e46abb-4ce5-4d98-9375-02378f649011
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Tue, 15 May 2018 10:21:11 GMT

{
  "error": {
    "code": "MissingProperty",
    "message": "Invalid or missing activities in HTTP body"
  }
}
```

I'd like to know what we are missing in this POST.

Comment: I'd like to know if the request body that you captured by fiddler `76{ "type": "message", "channelId": "directline", "from": { "id": "default-user", "name": "User" }, "text": "message text" }0` really contains **76** and **0**. Obviously it is not a valid activity entity. You could check if something wrong with your code of generating request body.

Comment: Yes, those numbers were parts of POST in fiddler.

In the end we've found out that Unity changed their POST implementation in 2017.3.X release a bit and they've started to use Transfer-Encoding: chunked Header, which caused those numbers to appear around our JSON. 

To prevent this behaviour all we needed to do was to add this line of code after creating UnityWebRequest:
webRequest.chunkedTransfer = false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [older version API](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-chunkedTransfer.html), the default value of **UnityWebRequest.chunkedTransfer** property is **true**,  as you mentioned, to prevent it, we can explicitly set:

```
UnityWebRequest.chunkedTransfer = false;
```

Besides, in [the latest version](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-chunkedTransfer.html), the default value of **UnityWebRequest.chunkedTransfer** property is **false**. So if upgrade and use the latest version, it might not cause this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

POST implementation in 2017.3.X release changed a bit and they've started to use Transfer-Encoding: chunked Header, which caused those numbers to appear around our JSON. To prevent this behaviour all we needed to do was to add this line of code after creating `UnityWebRequest: webRequest.chunkedTransfer = false;`